# Writing a function to calculate object properties whereas the object includes optional properties

Tags: typescript, function, option-type, required-field

I have a record of data (object-literal), and I need to calculate the average of several of its properties. For example, consider that each record reflects a sample of dog breeds and their weights. We have one representative for each breed, but two specific breeds may not appear in the data:

```js
// typescript

type dogSample = {
    // 5 core breeds that always appear
    bulldog: number,
    poodle: number,
    pug: number,
    chihuahua: number,
    boxer: number,
    // 2 additional that sometimes appear
    dalmatian?: number,
    rottweiler?: number, // rottweiler could appear only if dalmatian appears, but not vice versa
    // other irrelevant properties
    foo: string,
    bar: boolean,
    baz: number
    // and potentially hundreds of unrelated properties
}
```

My goal is to calculate the average of dogs weights. So I target those properties directly with three functions:

```js
const calcMeanCoreFive = (obj: dogSample) =>
  (obj.bulldog + obj.poodle + obj.pug + obj.chihuahua + obj.boxer) / 5;

const calcMeanCoreFivePlusDalmatian = (obj: Required<dogSample>) => // using `Required` solves type problem
  (obj.bulldog +
    obj.poodle +
    obj.pug +
    obj.chihuahua +
    obj.boxer +
    obj.dalmatian) /
  6;

const calcMeanCoreFivePlusDalmatianPlusRottw = (obj: Required<dogSample>) =>
  (obj.bulldog +
    obj.poodle +
    obj.pug +
    obj.chihuahua +
    obj.boxer +
    obj.dalmatian +
    obj.rottweiler) /
  7;
```

Finally I want to add a wrapper around all three versions such that:

```js
const calcMeanDogSample = (obj: dogSample, nBreeds: 5 | 6 | 7) =>
  nBreeds === 5
    ? calcMeanCoreFive(obj)
    : nBreeds === 6
    ? calcMeanCoreFivePlusDalmatian(obj)
//                                   ^
    : calcMeanCoreFivePlusDalmatianPlusRottw(obj);
//                                            ^
// argument of type 'dogSample' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Required<dogSample>'
```

*My attempt to work around this*

I tried to type `calcMeanDogSample()` with `Required<dogSample>`:

```js
const calcMeanDogSample2 = (obj: Required<dogSample>, nBreeds: 5 | 6 | 7) =>
  nBreeds === 5
    ? calcMeanCoreFive(obj)
    : nBreeds === 6
    ? calcMeanCoreFivePlusDalmatian(obj)
    : calcMeanCoreFivePlusDalmatianPlusRottw(obj);
```

This solves the error as far as the function's *definition*. However, calling `calcMeanDogSample2()` and passing an object of type `dogSample` wouldn't work:

```js
const someDogSample = {
  bulldog: 24,
  poodle: 33,
  pug: 21.3,
  chihuahua: 7,
  boxer: 24,
  dalmatian: 20,
  foo: "abcd",
  bar: false,
  baz: 123,
} as dogSample;

calcMeanDogSample2(someDogSample, 6);
//                     ^
// Argument of type 'dogSample' is not assignable to parameter of type // 'Required<dogSample>'.
//   Types of property 'dalmatian' are incompatible.
//     Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
//       Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
```

**My question**

Is there a way to type `calcMeanDogSample()` differently and solve this problem?

---

Reproducible code at [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAJg9gcwMoEMC2YA20C8UDeAUFFAEYCumm8CAXFAHblqkQBOA3MVGHHDNnpMW7LiTDk6jZq07cAxgAsAlovIo1KITNHdScAB7ttIuSRgpMaFMGUoGAfhOyxUNnGDAA7hGXY2TtKmrgD0IVAeiuxQymxsENgAbvbAPO6QbLYQAM7cAGZ89NnAbMoMCK6kKGz0%20nDY9pUoAF7OugC%20XITycAzFUPKW8gCyEPYAwnDxAGLKibhQABRwpABW9DSoGNgAlFA4AHzcy2sAdBRUNFAA1BFnvPzYN3erpxIIzyuvSqrqmp9nfRGNh7cIAVi6PT6qUGmBGYwYkxmcwgAAVMORsgARSzWWz2fZLbhfegAJQgAEdyLEIDAADybdBYCAHKBhKCYsofAAG5KpNJg3Kg2Xq82yUFAkDSK2waEIe0Oxy%2050o1EQN24JGVDwE0Gumpeb0kGpIWrOP00-31psNQOi1tNyosVhsdgYoO4ADZIb1%20rD4RMphBZvN0ZicS78Qww9lSR5vISTusoHzqfF6YztiyFUcSEmVZd1Q6za8dU9i4b3ibHeaVJb1NWS%20dDPaDU7ca6CRXle5PD4-OwPSQAOw%206EDIajexYxBbZmJkmwWdM7AAGkYACF4rTsvQwVAAD5QT2HqDDnPcBhbiA7-Y4PBgg0OCdwqeIoMhiBJnYGoTX2-3ngnpPi%20AbvsioYYtiHZRt%20v6gW%20SLBiiMYRniboxnGfbfmOfqTgiM7ICuEAAEwLmsZKUmmtIMsuWYHOuV7bjAu5QPuR4nke577Lmm7MeKgFsSB-qIR%20KJwTaf78XeQHCfhgYQWiUFoZ2DASaa9AiQiSGfqhMEYVBWHeDhhDdL6qQimgECEXOTx4EQJAXGqUgkQALKu3BlhA9AAMw%20R54iSPQJEAIynP5Ch1n86j0MOAVkC2NRQG58XOuh9jBQADPFBRwPQABEKCkPIMD5fFVRJXkljZBA5UtPQIUkRF7RQCg4qZsykLyQwNnESRiyWdZdHMuuno7FwQA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8EOrN) meet your needs?  If so I could write up the answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, it's a very nice solution indeed! Thank you! However, I'm unsure why you added the test `if (typeof v === "number")`. The properties `dalmatian` and `rottweiler` are already defined as `number` in the `dogSample` type.

Comment: ? If they are not present then the type will be `undefined` and not `number`.  You could test it yourself; remove `if (typeof v === "number")` and watch as `NaN` comes out.  Shall I write up an answer?

Comment: I see. But in that case, can't we more succinctly write `if (v) {...}`?

Comment: Anyhow, yes, please write it up! Many thanks.

Comment: No, `if (v)` will not distinguish `undefined` from `0`.  If you want `0` to be treated as if it's missing (i.e., that `nBreeds` doesn't increment) then sure, but that's a different algorithm from the one you provided.  I will write up the answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While one could implement your existing algorithm in a way the TypeScript compiler would recognize as type safe, my approach here would be to refactor the algorithm to something a bit more general:

```
const calcMeanDogSample = (obj: DogSample) => {
  let sum = obj.bulldog + obj.poodle + obj.pug + obj.chihuahua + obj.boxer;
  let nBreeds = 5;
  for (let v of [obj.dalmatian, obj.rottweiler]) {
    if (typeof v === "number") {
      sum += v; nBreeds++;
    }
  }
  return sum / nBreeds;
}
```

To get the mean, we need to divide the `sum` of the relevant properties by how many there are (`nBreeds`).  We can do the "core five" without worry because they are required properties.  For the [optionanl](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) `dalmatian` and `rottweiler` properties, we only want to contribute to `sum` and `nBreeds` if they are actually present.

You can verify that this behaves as expected:

```
const someDogSample = {
  bulldog: 24,
  poodle: 33,
  pug: 21.3,
  chihuahua: 7,
  boxer: 24,
  dalmatian: 20,
  foo: "abcd",
  bar: false,
  baz: 123,
};

console.log(calcMeanDogSample(someDogSample)); // 21.55
```

You could even refactor this more by transforming the list of keys to a list of possibly-defined numbers, filtering out the undefined values, and computing the mean of that:

```
const mean = (x: number[]) => x.reduce((a, v) => a + v, 0) / x.length;
const calcMeanDogSample2 = (obj: DogSample) => mean(
  (["bulldog", "poodle", "pug", "chihuahua", "boxer", "dalmatian", "rottweiler"] as const)
    .map(k => obj[k])
    .filter((v): v is number => typeof v === "number")
);
console.log(calcMeanDogSample2(someDogSample)); // 21.55
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gcwMoEMC2YA20C8UDeAUFFAEYCummAJogFxQB25apEATgNzFRhxzVsDZqw7cSYcgmEs2XHgGMAFgEsl5FOpQzR8kqTgAPDjrnio1FJjQpgKlIwD8psT3ZxgwAO4QV2ds5Msq4kAPShUB5KHFAq7OwQ2ABuDsC87pDsdhAAzjwAZvwMOcDsKowI5qQo7AwGcNgOVSgAXi7yAL7chApwjCVQClYKALIQDvDI6Fi4UAAUcKQAVgyTqBjYAJRQOAB8BDzYaTksO5HLAHQUVLQIUADU50sXfALYD08vUh+Lz8pqGi0P0uBmMeigRyYACEEhBqDkzgBWcyFdjzSFJSL5KAAbV+F0s1ls9kYABpPu5PD4-BwALrbIgkEgqbFzUCQODYzE4HlQABEIjkfIZPCZUBOaAeeCSnGhsPh93u5hIHR4qpICWA5HYjHFpwijBhEDhOW4qp6fQGOTgaAga2m7zwjLIlBo9CgACYACyknivQQQBgAZiDvokUgYHoAjBdQ4pVFotAwAOxhshGEyen08Qk2OwOSMABjThTgDD5KFICmofLT1VqUHyVhyEDrrQYUY9ca6hAt-QaEAumEQcyGmFG40Y9o2EDm1tt05mm02svCnpjiMRvb7A1tDjOc0M7Rx9J2+0MFwS1HIClncxQ5KS2z2UBQHyS5ML2wiF+wFWASjcL0-RpGOE4TIg6wzB6B6-KskEOhAz77HujBzDwcw4ny1xuggtb8v62D4Xykh4eSfL-ImGjEaCHDEbmxIOMRlLeL4-h8rSr4IsBJSbKKUAXDYYBzAA1meTw4iJ9L8Rc+R+MAHBzHMT4MJiKgIoKMQvuyECclA3K8gKwTsMKhArjuA5DiOYFjBBUwzh6c42naCEzsuq4RNGFyboQQA)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there's no correlation between `nBreeds` and the input `obj` in the type system.

However, TypeScript offers you a feature to inform the compiler that these properties do actually exist within your data if they can pass a conditional check: it's called a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) and its return type is called a *type predicate*. Here's an example of how to use it with your data, and — when you do — you no longer need to provide the `nBreeds` argument!

> See also the utility types [`Required<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) and [`Pick<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys)

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-xWswkhHDTTL2N3TjuMPY9+NohxhNEiyYKXAAqCbSL2-aDsOo68IAPTO3aBhuW1rhyW8wBqdArQ4GsK3yo1+xfBT3Q-FSv3eiBiQAImahxAbNPTX2+oy-u9IG4tGjgwfNLbQl2hg2J3PcuIPYTlq0xhNs4KBQh246yfJvazpOi7Bmu4Y7oetAnsXQdKxM8EIa+wzPxyoGQcYJGoBRngExITqbQxjj91LQnidJinyapnhLqGK56Yde72Eez4WdenKhdRrpE3XVMcjgJn9bwIh9CctsGAAJgAFkFCR3KEKAAGYPZd3gpAdgBGRtvcUVQiI0Bhkp98jaigJ2ff5h2AAYfcKOAGEBlBSAUahAajmoGHyKxZjztooH9+3g46Z03u9NcZp3HLyvNiAcq+bggA)

```ts
type DogSample = {
  bulldog: number;
  poodle: number;
  pug: number;
  chihuahua: number;
  boxer: number;
  dalmatian?: number;
  rottweiler?: number;
  // other irrelevant properties
  foo: string;
  bar: boolean;
  baz: number;
};

// This is called a user-defined type guard (and the return type is called a type predicate)
function sampleIncludesBreed <T extends DogSample, K extends keyof DogSample>(
  obj: T,
  breed: K,
): obj is T & Required<Pick<DogSample, K>> {
  return typeof (obj as Required<DogSample>)[breed] === 'number';
}

const calcMeanCoreFive = (obj: DogSample) =>
  (obj.bulldog + obj.poodle + obj.pug + obj.chihuahua + obj.boxer) / 5;

const calcMeanCoreFivePlusDalmatian = (obj: (
  DogSample
  & Required<Pick<DogSample, 'dalmatian'>>
)) =>
  (obj.bulldog +
    obj.poodle +
    obj.pug +
    obj.chihuahua +
    obj.boxer +
    obj.dalmatian) /
  6;

const calcMeanCoreFivePlusDalmatianPlusRottw = (obj: (
  DogSample
  & Required<Pick<DogSample, 'dalmatian'>>
  & Required<Pick<DogSample, 'rottweiler'>>
)) =>
  (obj.bulldog +
    obj.poodle +
    obj.pug +
    obj.chihuahua +
    obj.boxer +
    obj.dalmatian +
    obj.rottweiler) /
  7;

const calcMeanDogSample = (obj: DogSample) => {
  if (sampleIncludesBreed(obj, 'dalmatian')) {
    return sampleIncludesBreed(obj, 'rottweiler')
      ? calcMeanCoreFivePlusDalmatianPlusRottw(obj) /*
                                               ^^^
      This type is: (parameter) obj: DogSample & Required<Pick<DogSample, "dalmatian">> & Required<Pick<DogSample, "rottweiler">> */
      : calcMeanCoreFivePlusDalmatian(obj); /*
                                      ^^^
      This type is: (parameter) obj: DogSample & Required<Pick<DogSample, "dalmatian">> */
  }
  return calcMeanCoreFive(obj); /*
                          ^^^
  This type is: (parameter) obj: DogSample */
};

const someDogSample = {
  bulldog: 24,
  poodle: 33,
  pug: 21.3,
  chihuahua: 7,
  boxer: 24,
  dalmatian: 20,
  foo: "abcd",
  bar: false,
  baz: 123,
} as DogSample;

calcMeanDogSample(someDogSample);
```

> Completely unrelated to your question, but related to dogs and data: You might like the [API](https://dog.ceo/dog-api/) at [dog.ceo](https://dog.ceo/).